# Can we track illegal use of our tokenized item using NFT

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

I am in the phase of studying a project's viability. I want to build a blockchain based web application where a user can submit his/her piece of ART and convert it in Non-fungibel tokens and present it for selling. What i have learned is that we can limit the number of copies which can be created of each non-fungible token. However i am also interested that if we can track the usage of our item with the help of these NFTs as well? that means if a user buy my item let's say an image of mine which i have tokenized using NFT. can i track how many times this image has been used and where it is used ? my concern for tracking this info is to make sure that a proper license has been adopted before use and control illegal usage of the image.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> *can i track how many times this image has been used and where it is used ?*

Not on the blockchain.

---

NFT allows proving ownership of the token (representing an art piece for example) and other on-chain features such as setting the rules for transfer **of the token** (max amount of transfers, only pre-authorized transfers, etc).

But it's not possible to limit with on-chain tools what a user could do with the actual art piece off-chain (such as copying or other unlicensed use).